# Auto Clicker. Auto click button / image when It detected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, detection

Is it possible to create in any programming language "Auto clicker" that clicked automatically on button / image when It detects? I mean in this website: [example](http://www.118.lt/veiklu-sritys/prekyba-internetu--e-parduotuves/445?acttype=Prekyba%20internetu%20%28%20e%20-%20parduotuv%C4%97s%29&sq=1&p=10&actionId=14) are email buttons (icons), I need that program / script auto clicked these "icons" and sent emails (this part is easy with Outlook).
I've tried to use AC Tool, but It wont help, because It clicking on specific coordinates, not on button detected.

Maybe could you suggest any script or method how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: C# has got plugin called WatiN, what is really easy to use: http://watin.org/
In PHP you can use cURL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do that, but you can use jQuery / JavaScript to do that.

```
<button class="click_me">Click Me Automatically</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.click_me').click();
});

</script>
```

You could even use the $.each() function to click multiple buttons one after the other, if you'd like, though I think that would be really bad design.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Idea of what I want to do - automatically send message for multiple e-mails. I updated my question with screen shot which buttons I need to click. Can you suggest me better idea? I need to do 3 simple steps: 1. Click on icon 2. Paste text 3. Click "Send button" or click "Control + ENTER". That's all. After It should click other icon and repeat steps. Have you idea?

Comment: I made that with "AC Tool" but here is no function to detect button, It clicking specific coordinates. And as you see these buttons / icons  are added randomly not in 1 column, that's why I need to detect It.

Comment: OH.. so you're wanting to click the button in someone else's website?  I thought you meant in one you were building.  You may need something built with Behat and Mink to do that.